# Current location alert and dot not showing in iOS8

Tags: ios8, alert, core-location, cllocationmanager, xcode6

Moving from iOS7 to iOS8, my app is not showing either the alert or the blue dot for the current location. I tried to change my code according to what I've read on here and now the alert is showing but for just a split second, not giving the chance to select anything. Needless to say that the blue dot is not there either.
My code is:

**MapName.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MapName : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *MapName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLRegion *region;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL showsUserLocation;

@end
```

**MapName.m**

```
//in the (void)viewDiDLoad section
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate = _MapName;  //Assigning to 'id<CLLocationManagerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'MKMapView*_strong' warning showing here
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied ||
    status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
    //UIApplication -openUrl: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString //this is the example shown on WWDC
}

[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:_region];
```

I've added NSLocationWhenIsUseUsageDescription string with a message (which I see in the alert) to the Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

**MapName.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface MapName : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *MapName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

**MapName.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

//Center the map
[self gotoLocation];

//Show current position
_MapName.showsUserLocation = YES;

}
```

Adding the key NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription as a string to the Info.plist first